# Decode Hex String in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2, converting the hexadecimal form of a string into the corresponding unicode was straightforward:

```
comments.decode("hex")
```

where the variable 'comments' is a part of a line in a file (the rest of the line does *not* need to be converted, as it is represented only in ASCII.

Now in Python 3, however, this doesn't work (I assume because of the bytes/string vs. string/unicode switch. I feel like there should be a one-liner in Python 3 to do the same thing, rather than reading the entire line as a series of bytes (which I don't want to do) and then converting each part of the line separately. If it's possible, I'd like to read the entire line as a unicode string (because the rest of the line is in unicode) and only convert this one part from a hexadecimal representation.

Comment: I'm not sure that hex encoding strings makes all that much sense. If you want to store an incompatible encoding I'd at least use base 64 because it is more efficient. That doesn't invalidate the question / answer in any way of course, maybe somebody else decided upon hex.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Something like:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('4a4b4c').decode('utf-8')
'JKL'
```

Just put the actual encoding you are using.

Comment: Unless the decoded string *is* actually utf-8, I would recommend using `decode('ascii')` instead.

Comment: @Ja͢ck You could encode to hex if you knew that the Unicode string is incompatible with the encoding used for storing the string. If a string is already known to be ASCII then there is no need to encode it it as a hexadecimal string in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't work for all hex strings, though. For instance, `bytes.fromhex('82').decode('utf-8')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError`. Using `'ascii'` format doesn't fix the problem, since that will fail for bytes with values >127.

Comment: That's because 0x82 really isn't a valid UTF-8 sequence. Your comment is trivially true in that hex strings which aren't valid UTF-8 cannot be decoded, but that would be true for any other representation of those sequences too.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There are reasons to encode to hex even if it's already ASCII. For example if you want to use it as a file name, you might want to avoid having any characters such as '/' or '\', and hex encoding would fix that.

Comment: @Buge That's a good point, although base64url might make more sense for that particular use case.

Answer (score 25):

```
import codecs

decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")

# for an array
msgs = [decode_hex(msg)[0] for msg in msgs]

# for a string
string = decode_hex(string)[0]
```

Comment: This method is universal and works great for both py2 and py3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answers from @unbeli and @Niklas are good, but @unbeli's answer does not work for all hex strings and it is desirable to do the decoding without importing an extra library (codecs). The following should work (but will not be very efficient for large strings):

```py
>>> result = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s)//2)) % tuple(s))('4a82fdfeff00')).decode('utf-16-le')
>>> result == '\x4a\x82\xfd\xfe\xff\x00'
True
```

Basically, it works around having invalid utf-8 bytes by padding with zeros and decoding as utf-16.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how UTF-8 works. But if your input is UTF-16 (or more properly the pure 16-bit UCS-2 subset) this is useful.

Comment: This is almost what I need, just the other way around. My input is like: "abc\xFBdef" How can I get back the utf8 string from it?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to decode a **byte string**, that might **miss a char** a the end.

As bytes in hex are of size 2, `codecs` didn't work. So I had to write a little function.

```py
def decode_hexstring(hexstring):
    decoded = ''

    for i in range(0, len(hexstring), 2):
        b = hexstring[i:i+2]
        b = b.decode() # it's a byte-string

        try:
            c = bytes.fromhex(b).decode()
        except: # the last char might be missing
            c = '☐'

        decoded = decoded + c

    return decoded

print(decode_hexstring(b'737030306b792d686578737472696e676'))
```

```
sp00ky-hexstring☐
```