# Decode base64 string in python 3 (with lxml or not)

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, lxml

I know this looks embarrassingly easy, and I guess the problem is that I just don't have a clear understanding of all this *bytes-str-unicode* (and *encoding-decoding*, speaking frankly) stuff yet.

I've been trying to get my working code to run on Python 3. The part I'm stuck with is when I parse an XML with `lxml` and decode a base64 string that is in that XML.

The code now works in the following manner:

I retrieve the binary data with an XPath query `'.../binary/text()'`. This produces a one-element list containing a `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` object. Then, with python 2, I was able to do:

```py
decoded = source.decode('base64')
```

and finally

```py
output = numpy.frombuffer(decoded)
```

However, on python 3 I get an error message saying

```py
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

This is not so surprising, because `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` is a subclass of `str`.

Another way would be to get a real `str` with the same data in it with

```py
 binary = tree.xpath('//binary')[0]
 binary_string = binary.text
```

That would be essentially the same. So what do I do to decode it from base64? I've looked at the `base64` module, but it takes a `bytes` object as an argument, and I can't think of the way to present `str` as `bytes`, because if I try to construct a `bytes` object, Python will try to **encode** the string, which I don't need.

Googling further, I came across the `binascii` module (which is invoked indirectly from `base64` anyway, if I'm not mistaken), but calling `binascii.b2a_base64()` on my string produces

```py
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

P.S. I've even found an answered question on [how to decode a hex string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3), but this is done with a dedicated method `bytes.fromhex()` so I don't see how it would be helpful.

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing? I'm afraid most of the post is irrelevant and only aggravates my shame, but at least you guys know [what I tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: As an aside, Ned Batchelder has a great presentation on this bytes-str-unicode stuff: [Pragmatic Unicode, or: How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: Thank @delnan, I'm halfway through and really helps a lot already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Python 3 installed, but it sounds like you need to convert the Unicode returned from lxml to bytes, perhaps by calling .encode('ascii') ?

Comment: Gosh... I knew it was easy. I just can't settle this stuff in my mind the way it should be. I've been thinking about my string as something *encoded*, so it really didn't occur to me that I need to encode it to get `bytes`. Thanks.

Comment: Think of Unicode as plain-vanilla-strings that need to be encoded when they're going to "hardware" and decoded when coming from "hardware" :-)

Comment: I felt like such a long question needed a longer answer, but anyway, many thanks for pointing the right direction :)

Answer (score 13):

OK, I think I'm going to summarize my current understanding of things (feel free to correct me). Hopefully it will help someone else out there as confused as I've been.

The credit totally goes to [thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75103/thebjorn) and [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan), of course.

So, starting with the most common things:
there's [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and it's a global standard that assigns codes (or code points) to all the exotic characters you can imagine. Those codes are just integer numbers. As of Unicode 6.1 there are 109,975 graphic characters, says Wikipedia.

Then there are encodings that define how to designate Unicode characters with byte codes. One byte isn't enough to designate an arbitrary Unicode char. Although, if you only take a small subset of them (English alphabet, digits, punctuation, some control characters), you can do with one byte per character (or even 7 bits; see [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

---

To pass a Unicode string anywhere, one needs to encode it in bytes, then it can be decoded on the other end.

In Python 2, `str` is actually bytes, and `unicode` is Unicode, but Python 2 will do implicit encoding/decoding for you when needed. It will try to use ASCII encoding.

In Python 3, `str` is always a Unicode string, and `bytes` is a new data type for actual bytes. No implicit conversion is ever done by Python 3, you always need to do it yourself and specify the encoding. That means that your program won't work until you understand what's going on, which totally happened to me.

---

Now, that being more or less clear, let's move on to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding, which is also an encoding of sorts, but has a slightly different meaning.
Suppose you have some binary data (i.e. *bytes*) that may mean anything (in my case it's a bunch of `float`s). Now you want to represent this binary array with a string. That's what base64 encoding means: you have your bytes represented as an ASCII string.

Base64 means 6 bit, so in a base64-encoded string a single character stands for 6 bits of your data. That is why base64-encoded strings need to have the length that is a multiple of 4: otherwise the number of bytes encoded will be not integer.

---

Finally, to decode from base64 you need an ASCII string. A Unicode string won't do, there can only be characters from the base64 alphabet. [Base64 module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/base64.html) does the job in Python. The `base64.b64decode()` function takes a **byte string** as the argument. In Python 2 it means: `str`. In Python 3 it means: `bytes`. So if you have a `str`, such as

```
>>> s = 'U3RhY2sgT3ZlcmZsb3c='
```

In Python 2 you could just do

```
>>> s.decode('base64')
```

because `s` is already in ASCII.
In Python 3, you need to **encode it in ASCII** first, so you'll have to do:

```
>>> base64.b64decode(s.encode('ascii'))
```

And by the way, this will return a `bytes` object, so it's really up to you how to treat those bytes then. Maybe it's my floats, but maybe you should try to decode it as ASCII :)
In Python 2 however it will be just a `str`. Anyway, have a look at [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for the tools to unpack your data from those bytes.

So if you need the code to work on both Python 2 and 3, go with the last one. To make sure you have Unicode in the end (if you are decoding text from base64), you'll have to decode it:

```
>>> base64.b64decode(s.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
```

On Python 2, `encode('ascii')` won't effectively do anything because it's applied to `str`. So it will do an *implicit conversion* to Unicode first, and then do what you want (convert it back to ASCII). `decode('ascii')` will return a `unicode` object on Python 2.

Comment: Excellent summary :-)  If you're trying to save a list of floats, perhaps the pickle module will be easier than the struct module?  Something like base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps([2.718, 3.141]))

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks :) I'm actually using `numpy.frombuffer()`, I just mentioned `struct` for reference, to account for a general case.

Comment: "your program won't work until you understand what's going on" -- this is a Good Thing, most of the time. :)

Comment: Indeed, and it didn't take too much time anyway.