# What is the type of an "utf8" string encoding in Python?

Tags: python, string, encoding, python-2.x

I'm using Python 2.7

I'm reading a file containing "iso-8859-1" coded information.
After parsing, I get the results in strings, ie `s1`:

```
>>> s1
'D\xf6rfli'
>>> type(s1)
<type 'str'>
>>> s2=s1.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf8")
>>> s2
'D\xc3\xb6rfli'
>>> type(s2)
<type 'str'>
>>> print s1, s2
D�rfli Dörfli
>>>
```

Why is the type of `s2` still a `str` after the call to `.encode`?
How can I convert it from `str` to `utf-8`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but what makes you think `utf-8` is a type? Also, the output is as expected; what more do you want?

Comment: This presentation may help you understand the fundamentals:  [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain?](http://bit.ly/unipain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your questions, but here's what I observed.

If you just want to get the string into a printable form, just stop after calling decode. I'm not sure why you are trying to encode into UTF8 after successfully converting from is8859 into unicode.

```
>>> s1 = 'D\xf6rfli'
>>> s1
'D\xf6rfli'
>>> s2 = s1.decode("iso-8859-1")
>>> s2
u'D\xf6rfli'
>>> print s2
Dörfli
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`str` in Python 2 means an *encoded* string, i.e. a sequence of bytes. This is documented behavior. The *decoded* `str` would be of type `unicode`.

`UTF-8` is an **encoding**, as well as `ISO-8859-1`. So you just decode your string and then encode in another encoding, producing data of the same type.

On the contrary, in Python 3 `str` would be a text string (in Unicode) and calling `encode` on it would give you an instance of `bytes`.

So, in Python 2, a UTF-8 string will be `str`, because it is encoded.

I second the recommendation by Ned: take a look at the [presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) he links to (oh my, is it his own talk?). It helped me a lot when I was [struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10019268/1258041) with these things.

Comment: Good explanation, except you used `decode` instead of `encode` in the line about Python 3.

Comment: So, if I right understand, `unicode` is NOT like "utf-8" encoded `str`?

Comment: @jdpiguet Correct. `unicode` is a Unicode string, not encoded at all.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer to the "Why" question! :)