# Convert hexadecimal to normal string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.3.2 and I want convert a hex to a string.

```
This is my code:
junk = "\x41" * 50 # A
eip = pack("<L", 0x0015FCC4)
buffer = junk + eip
```

I've tried use

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify("4142")
b'AB'
```

... but I want the output "AB", no "b'AB'". What can I do?

Edit:

```
buffer = junk + binascii.unhexlify(eip).decode('ascii')
```

**binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found**

The problem is I can't concatenate junk + eip.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode Hex String in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3)

Comment: mm.. no. I want concatenate no representable characters (\x90 for example).

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

What that `b` stands for is to denote that is a `bytes` class, i.e. a string of bytes.  If you want to convert that into a string you want to use the decode method.

```
>>> type(binascii.unhexlify(b"4142"))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> binascii.unhexlify(b"4142").decode('ascii')
'AB'
```

This results in a string, which is a string of unicode characters.

Edit:

If you want to work purely with binary data, don't do decode, stick with using the bytes type, so in your edited example:

```
>>> #- junk = "\x41" * 50 # A
>>> junk = b"\x41" * 50 # A
>>> eip = pack("<L", 0x0015FCC4)
>>> buffer = junk + eip
>>> buffer
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xc4\xfc\x15\x00'
```

Note the `b` in `b"\x41"`, which denote that as a binary string, i.e. standard string type in python2, or literally a string of bytes rather than a string of unicode characters which are two completely different things.

Comment: It's a part of an exploit, and buffer contain hexadecimal characters no playable in ascii-mode or utf-8-mode (\x90 por example), but ty.

Comment: Then you should just leave it as a bytestring if that's binary data.

Comment: junk = b"\x41" * 50 # A
eip = pack("<L", 0x0015FCC4)
buffer = junk + eip

Only with this method? Ugly code xD. Thank you!

Comment: Representation of strings types have changed completely from python2 to python3. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a literal representation. Don't worry about the `b`, as it's not actually part of the string itself.

See [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269765/139010)

Comment: Oh, better :)
But I can't concatenate eip to junk :/