# Python decode unexpected behavior on hex string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, decode

I have an hexa string that I want to convert to a numpy array of int.

I don't want to use `for` loops because looping through numpy arrays is not advised.

So I do the following :

`vector = np.fromstring( s.decode('hex'), dtype=np.uint8 )`

If for example `s = 'a312'`, `s.decode('hex')` returns `'\xa3\x12'` which is correct.

But if `s = 'a320'`, `s.decode('hex')` returns `'\xa3 '` which seems a little bit weird as first sight because I expect `'\xa3\x20'`.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that a binary string in Pyhon is **represented** as its **ASCII equivalent**.

The **equivalent of `'\x20'` is a space**, as one can see in the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters):

> ```
> Hex  Dec  ASCII
>  20   32    (space)
> ```

If you write `'\x20'` in the terminal, it will print a space:

```
>>> '\x20'
' '
>>> 'a320'.decode('hex') == '\xa3\x20'
True
```

Note that this is only an **aspect of representation**: behind the curtains, the binary string contains the `0010 0000` binary value.

Comment: Ok I see. I guess maybe `decode`is not what I need.

How can I get `'\xa3\x20'` from a `s = 'a320'` ?

Comment: @SebMa: did you read the answer carefully? You get `\xa3\x20`. It is all a matter of how a **string is represented**.

Comment: You are right, it's the end of the day, I'm starting to get tired.

`decode()` does what I want in the end and I get the expected integer value : `np.fromstring( '\xa3 ', dtype=np.uint8 )[1]`

Comment: With python3, `s.decode('hex')` does not work : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`, how can I make the code work in both python2 and python3 ?

Comment: @SebMa: In Python-3.x there is indeed no decode. You can use [`bytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284069/67579) for that. Besides that Python-2.x and Python-3.x are actually two different languages. Making a program that works on both is in theory possible, but very hard (since for instance `map`, `zip`, etc. all have different behavior).