# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' Having this error on the second line of my code

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

This is my code,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    key = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef".decode('hex')  /this line is having error
    plain_1 = "1weqweqd"
    plain_2 = "23444444"
    plain_3 = "dddd2225"
    print(plain_1)
    print(plain_2)
    print(plain_3)

    cipher = Present(key)
```

**Output**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: `str` has a decode method in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Comment: Use: `binascii.unhexlify('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef')`

Comment: Somebody had similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3

Comment: you want to decode the hexadecimal number and you are trying to decode string i think that could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you try to decode a string. `bytes` type can be decoded but not `str` type. You should encode (`key.encode()`) this (or use `b"foo"`) before, to convert the string to a `bytes` object.

```
>>> foo = "adarcfdzer"
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
>>> foo = foo.encode()
>>> type(foo)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> foo = foo.decode()
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
```